# Multitextures is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I am using 3 textures.But only two textures are working.

```
enum {
UNIFORM_TEXTURE,
UNIFORM_TEXTURE_MAP,
UNIFORM_INPUT1,
NUM_UNIFORMS};
GLint uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS];
```

The third one is not displaying .This is how I activate the textures:

```
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // second texture

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName1);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    // thrid texture 
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName2);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);


glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE], 0);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE_MAP], 1);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_INPUT1],2);

uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE] = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture");
uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE_MAP] = glGetUniformLocation(program,"texture2");
uniforms[UNIFORM_INPUT1]= glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture3");
```

In my shader I call only the third texture to check it.

```
highp vec4 texel = texture2D(texture3,texCoordVarying);
highp vec2 coord = 0.5 * (texel.xy / 0.8);
gl_FragColor = vec4(coord,0,0);
```

Here how I load the texture :

```
- (void)loadTexture:(GLuint *)newTextureName fromFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    // Load image from file and get reference
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil]];
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];

    if(imageRef) {
        // get width and height
        size_t imageWidth = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
        size_t imageHeight = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

        GLubyte *imageData = (GLubyte *)malloc(imageWidth * imageHeight * 4);
        memset(imageData, 0, (imageWidth * imageHeight * 4));

        CGContextRef imageContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, imageWidth, imageHeight, 8, imageWidth * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

        // Make CG system interpret OpenGL style texture coordinates properly by inverting Y axis
        CGContextTranslateCTM(imageContextRef, 0, imageHeight);
        CGContextScaleCTM(imageContextRef, 1.0, -1.0);

        CGContextDrawImage(imageContextRef, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)imageWidth, (CGFloat)imageHeight), imageRef);

        CGContextRelease(imageContextRef);

        glGenTextures(1, newTextureName);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *newTextureName);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imageWidth, imageHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

        free(imageData);

        glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }

    [image release];
 }

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    EAGLContext *aContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:2];

if (!aContext)
    NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
else if (![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:aContext])
    NSLog(@"Failed to set ES context current");

self.context = aContext;
[aContext release];

[(EAGLView *)self.view setContext:context];
[(EAGLView *)self.view setFramebuffer];

[self loadShaders];

[self loadTexture:&textureName fromFile:@"image.png"];
[self loadTexture:&textureName1 fromFile:@"image1.png"];
[self loadTexture:&textureName2 fromFile:@"image2.png"];
GLint framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight;

glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &framebufferWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT,&framebufferHeight);


[self drawFrame];
}
```

Comment: any shader?whats uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE]?

Comment: what you except from this code? there is not any composition between your textures in GLSL code.I dont know what you except

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by there is not any composition between textures ??

Comment: in another word,what do you mean by not working?

Comment: in OpenGL code i don't see anything wrong.put more detail of GLSL Code

Comment: especially uniform declaration in GLSL code

Comment: The uniform declaration is an enum type.I put the declaration above.

Comment: what I mean but it's not working,all my textures seem to be loaded and the uniform seems working too.But when I try the third texture by displaying it through the fragment shader,nothing happens,it's some how only two textures can be used in the shader.

Comment: if you declare  **GLint uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS]** youre lookup texture must be like this highp vec4 texel =texture2D(uniforms[UNIFORM_INPUT1],texCoordVarying);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the feeling there are other issues, but for starters...

You want to get the uniform locations BEFORE you upload values to those locations.  So you declared your array

`GLint uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS]`

You are using the array to store your uniform locations (maybe you can rename it to `uniformLocations`?)  You then proceed to call `glUniform1i`, using the locations stored in `uniforms'.  Since the contents are undefined, who knows what is happening to the values you are using.

After you upload the uniform values, you THEN query the uniform locations with `glGetUniformLocation`, which populates your array.  You should query, then upload.  So change the code to this:

```
uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE] = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture");
uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE_MAP] = glGetUniformLocation(program,"texture2");
uniforms[UNIFORM_INPUT1]= glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture3");

glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE], 0);
glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE_MAP], 1);
glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_INPUT1],2);
```

On top of that, you might want to use glGetError to debug your code.  You can put it at certain part of your code to narrow down issues, or create a macro where it calls glGetError and asserts on any error, and insert that macro after every OGL call.

Answer (score 0):

Well I find the issue for the third texture I add two another glTexParameteri
like that :

```
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

      // second texture
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName2);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

And the shader receives the third texture.